# Proxychains firefox issue

Tags: firefox, kali-linux

I am unable to open firefox using proxychains. I get this error

```
rootkali)-[/home/kali]
└─# proxychains firefox www.whatsmyip.org                                                                                                                          1 ⨯
[proxychains] config file found: /etc/proxychains4.conf
[proxychains] preloading /usr/lib/x86_64-linux-gnu/libproxychains.so.4
[proxychains] DLL init: proxychains-ng 4.14
[proxychains] DLL init: proxychains-ng 4.14
[proxychains] DLL init: proxychains-ng 4.14
Running Firefox as root in a regular user's session is not supported.  ($XAUTHORITY is /home/kali/.Xauthority which is owned by kali.)
```

but if I enter this command

```
XAUTHORITY=/root/.Xauthority sudo firefox
```

firefox runs normally.